# Why I cannot use ZRANGEBYLEX on this sorted set in redis?

Tags: redis

In the redis documentation, there is this example of `ZRANGEBYLEX`

```
ZADD myindex 0 0056:0028.44:90
ZADD myindex 0 0034:0011.00:832
ZRANGEBYLEX myindex [0056:0010.00 [0056:0030.00
1) "0056:0028.44:90"
```

It is very straightforward.

However if I want to apply the same technique to the following example,

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd feedbacks 1 feedback1 2 feedback2 3 feedback3 1 feedback4
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX feedbacks [feed [feed
(empty list or set)
```

I get an empty set.

I would expect to see the four values (`feedback1` to `feedback4`)

Why `ZRANGEBYLEX` failed on my test sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails because they have different scores. ZRANGEBYLEX works only on same-score subsets.

See https://redis.io/commands/ZRANGEBYLEX

> When all the elements in a sorted set are inserted **with the same**
>   **score**, in order to force lexicographical ordering, this command
>   returns all the elements in the sorted set at key with a value between
>   min and max.
>
> **If the elements in the sorted set have different scores, the returned**
>   **elements are unspecified**.

Sorted sets have the property of being lexicographically ordered within same-score subsets. This gives them a second use-case, a lexicographically sorted set, but in this case, you add all elements with the same score.

So, you have to choose how to use your sorted set:

- Sorted by score (with same-score sorted lex, for predictable order)
- Sorted lexicographically, all elements given the same score

You cannot have both. You'd need two sorted sets then.

Comment: I have strings in set having same score assigned i.e. 1. Still, I am getting an empty array in result. `[
  'Einflüssen', '1',
  'Jüpïtër',    '1',
  'Mǟrs',       '1',
  'Sǟtürn',     '1',
  'Versalhöhe', '1',
  'Vënüs',      '1',
  'stören',     '1',
  'Ëarth',      '1' 
]` and the command I am using is, `zrangebylex search [Ei [Ein`

Comment: From the strings you provided, none is within `[Ei [Ein`

Comment: Okay. I was little confused about min and max ranges in `zrangebylex`. I tried it with `zrangebylex search [Ei [Einflüssen` and it worked. But, if I want all the strings that match atleast `[Ein` to be present in my result, what should be the max range? Can you please suggest?

Comment: You do the immediate next (in byte/char code) , exclusive, at the end: `(Eio`

Comment: Thats a problem cause when you Zrange BYSCORE and if you include 9 as min and 9 as max score, it returns all members with 9 score same behaviour is not implemented by BYLEX..  :( a.k.a [Ei [Ei